# Cannot connect to mysql using Node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to connect to mysql but I am getting the following error :
"Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ' root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

But when I connect using mysql command line client I am able to connect to mysql.
Here is my config.js file where I have defined the connectivity settings :

```js
//config.js
var mysql  = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          port     : '3306',
          user     : ' root',
          password : 'root',
          database : 'world'
        });
module.exports = connection;
```

I am trying to connect to the db in this file :

```js
// userController.js
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var connection = require("../config.js");
var auth = {
 
  getAll: function(req, res) {
 
   console.log("in user comtroller");
 console.log(connection);
  connection.connect(function(err) {
      // connected! (unless `err` is set)
      if(err){
        console.log("Failed to connect to mysql. Error : "+err);
      }
      else{
        console.log("connection Successful..!!");
      }
    });
 res.send("going good");
 
    
  }
 
}
 
module.exports = auth;
```

Comment: Redundant space here? `user     : ' root'`

Comment: Try giving your IP name in the localhost place. 2nd I did not understand what you meant when you say password YES.